# How to determine the value is from user request or it's just the default value in .NET for numeric types

Tags: c#, web-services, numeric

How to determine the value is from user request or it's just the default value in .NET for numeric types?
My application is a .NET web service.

I have been stuck for a long time.

Comment: Is it an ASMX or WCF web service?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot. A value object *will* have a value, and once it is a default value (0 for numeric type) you cannot distinguish whether it has been set by user or "just happened" by default.

What you can do is to use nullable types (in C# the notation is `Nullable<int>` or `int?`) and then check if their `.HasValue` property.

Answer (score 0):

For double, use double.NaN (not a valid number).